# Mod_wsgi syntax error: "Invalid command import"

Tags: python, mod-wsgi, django-wsgi

i'm trying to setup mod_wsgi to serve my django media files (i want to use this also in a developement env)

I followed [this guide](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/django_apache_and_mod_wsgi) to correctly setup mod_wsgi.

This is my wsgi file ("django.wsgi")

```
import os, sys

path = '/home/smau/Workspace/Maynard/tothego_frontend/'
if path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(path)

#Calculate the path based on the location of the WSGI script.
apache_configuration= os.path.dirname(__file__)
project = os.path.dirname(apache_configuration)
workspace = os.path.dirname(project)
sys.path.append(workspace)

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'tothego_frontend.settings' 

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

This is my conf file ("django.conf")

```
Alias /site_media/ "/home/smau/Workspace/Maynard/tothego_frontend/site_media/"
<Directory "/home/smau/Workspace/Maynard/tothego_frontend/site_media">
Order allow,deny
Options Indexes
Allow from all
IndexOptions FancyIndexing
</Directory>

WSGIScriptAlias / "/home/smau/Workspace/Maynard/tothego_frontend/srv/mod_wsgi/django.wsgi"

<Directory "/home/smau/Workspace/Maynard/tothego_frontend/srv/mod_wsgi">
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

This is my "httpd.conf"

```
Include /home/smau/Workspace/Maynard/tothego_frontend/srv/mod_wsgi/django.wsgi
```

Everything seems to be like the guide, however, when i try to start/restart apache i get this error

```
root@archimedes:/etc/apache2# /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
Syntax error on line 1 of /home/smau/Workspace/Maynard/tothego_frontend/srv/mod_wsgi/django.wsgi:
Invalid command 'import', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
   ...fail!
```

This is /var/log/apache2.log

```
[Thu Jul 14 11:39:31 2011] [notice] Apache/2.2.17 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.3.5-1ubuntu7.2 
with Suhosin-Patch mod_wsgi/3.3 Python/2.7.1+ configured -- resuming normal operations

[Thu Jul 14 11:44:28 2011] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 
'/usr/lib/php5/20090626/gd.so'- /usr/lib/php5/20090626/gd.so: cannot open shared object file: 
No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
```

The log doesn't seem (to me...) anyhow related to my problem. Why do i keep getting the "import" error? Did i give you enought information or do you need something else? I guess my pythonpath is correct:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're supposed to include the configuration file (django.conf), not the WSGI script (django.wsgi).

Comment: that's what happens when you work too much, you don't notice the smallest trivial errors... thanks!